# How does Captain America return the stones when some of them are not even in their original forms?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

How does Captain America return the Infinity Stones at the end of *Avengers: Endgame* when some of them are not even in their original forms? The space stone in the Tesseract, reality stone in Aether, which is fluid-like, e.g. I assume the Avengers broke all the stones' containers when they assembled their gauntlet.

Comment: not only if someone can answer all the questions here.

Comment: I had the same question myself; and almost asked it before finding that other one. It would be great if there were any sort of good answer, even if it does come down to "they built a new Tesseract off screen."

Comment: haha, with some hot glue and gorilla glass. It would be tough with Aether tho, which is kinda a scary lurking slime

Comment: More a kind of angry sludge.